# Hide the wpf context menu over the area where there is no rows in the wpf datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I have a WPF datagrid populated with datas. And I put a context menu on the row  items when right clicking on the  datarow. But the context menu is showing on the outside of datarow as  well. I hid the context menu on the column header as show below:

```
    <Style x:Key="dgHeaderStyle" TargetType="dg:DataGridColumnHeader">

       <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
           <Setter.Value>
               <ContextMenu Visibility="Collapsed" />
           </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
    </Style>
```

But how to hide/collapsed the context menu on the outside of the datagrid row?

I defined the context menu in the xaml as shown below:

```
    <dg:DataGrid.ContextMenu>
           <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Update" Name="mnuUpdate" Click="mnuUpdate_Click" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </dg:DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

I changed defining the context menu in grid.rowstyle. but it throws below shown error.

[image: contextmenu]

Comment: I don't understand your question. Does the context menu show up where you right-click outside of the row?

Comment: Yes. If we right click on outside of the row, the context menu dsiplays. I want to hide the context menu in that case.

Comment: I defined context menu in the xaml.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ContextMenu` for `DataGrid` <del>`dg:DataGrid.ContextMenu`</del> and add it for the row:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Update" Name="mnuUpdate" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: It worked fine only for one time. I am getting exceptions @ system level. When i am invoking the window which contains the datagrid by double clicking on the listboxitem, it throws error - "Set connectionId threw an exception". The inner message of the stack says - "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.Button'."}

Comment: There is an error when using your code. I updated the question and added a new comment. please look

Comment: The error is not in my code, but in yours. The problem is in content of event handler.